# How to use single form for editing data in ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am working on a project which uses codeigniter framework. I am able to display all data from database into a table. What I did is loop the result and every row has its edit link. Now, the problem is everytime I load the page, all edit links are forms loaded at the same time. For example, when I have more than a hundred data from the DB, hundred edit forms also looping which I think not good for the system because of its heaviness. What I plan is to use a single form and just pass the data using ajax. Can anyone know how to do it? I just need some guidance. Thanks in advance.

EXAMPLE CODE:

```
<?php foreach ($users as $key => $value): ?>
<tr>
 <td><?php echo $value['first_name'] ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $value['last_name'] ?></td>
 <td>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#update_user_modal<?php echo    $value['id'] ?>" id="view-profile" title="Click to view">
   <i class="icon-doc"></i>
  </a>
 </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach to this problem:
you keep one form in a modal and in your edit link attach a onclick event in jquery which will push data to your modal form .
then trigger the modal open inside click event function .I have just show a demonastration not complete solution .

```
in your edit section do below

    <td>
     <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" 
class = "some-action-class"
                data-target="#update_user_modal"
                data-userID="<?php echo $value['id'] ?>"
                data-userFname="<?php echo $value['first_name'] ?>"
                data-userLname="<?php echo $value['last_name'] ?>" 
                id="view-profile" 
                title="Click to view">
            <i class="icon-doc"></i>
           </a>
   </td>
```

here the JS code:

```
$(".some-action-class").on('click', function () {
    //here push data to modal form input element like below
    var inputOne = document.getElementById('someInputId') ; //in you modal form      
    var userID = $( this ).data( "userID" );
   //set clicked row value to modal 
   inputOne.val(userID);
   //do like above for other fields 

    $('#update_user_modal').modal('show');//modal opens with updated value 
});
```

hide the modal when done editing:

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll try this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a modal with a form and then call it with Ajax.

First add a class to your `td` so that we can pull out its value. Also, I've added a icon to click on for editing

```
<tr>
 <td class="first_name"><?php echo $value['first_name'] ?></td>
 <td class="last_name"><?php echo $value['last_name'] ?></td>
 <td>
  <a href="#" data-id="<?php echo $value['id'] ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#update_user_modal" id="view-profile" title="Click to view">
   <i class="icon-doc"></i>
   <i class="icon-edit"></i>
  </a>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Now, call your form with Ajax(maybe a BS modal) but first we need to get the values of the row you are trying to change:

```
$(document).on('click', '.icon-edit', function(){
    // get values required for editing
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    var first_name = $(this).closest('tr').find('.first_name').text();
    var last_name = $(this).closest('tr').find('.last_name').text();

   // Do Ajax call
    $.ajax({
      url:"path/to/form.php?id=" + id + "&first_name=" + first_name + "&last_name=" + last_name,
      success:function(data){
        //append form to your DOM
        $('element').html(data);
      },    
    })
});
```

Now in your PHP script and HTML form, you can set a the `input` value and with it `isset()`you can identify if its a edit or add. Take a look at this:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input name="first_name" value="<?php isset($_GET['first_name']) ? $_GET['first_name'] : "" ; ?>">
    <input name="last_name" value="<?php isset($_GET['last_name']) ? $_GET['last_name'] : "" ; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        // Do query to update
    }else{
        // Do query to create   
    }

}

?>
```

Or you can just to a Ajax call to update/create a user.

Comment: I'll try this out. Thanks!

Comment: `path/to/form.php?id=` is this the action link for the form?

Comment: @claudios Its the path to the form itself.

Comment: How about adding a url like this? `var url  = $(form_id).attr("action");` then use it like, url: url

Answer (score 0):

You are using the model popup for the update as you have written in the data-target and you have created model per record.

But You can do like this. You can create only one model popup like #update_data and on click of that Edit link create the ajax call and get the data using record_id and fill that data in model. Then open that model and for update also you can create ajax to update the record for the selected record_id.

on success you can update the row of the list data.

Comment: Thanks, I get your point. Can you show me a lil bit on how to do it exactly? just to know if I can get the record id of each row selected. Thanks